# AWS MTURK SDK: Extract Data from Hit Info?

Tags: aws-sdk, mechanicalturk

I have successfully retrieved info on my HIT using the SDK:

```
        $hitInfo = $this->mturk->getHIT([
            'HITId' => $hit_id,
        ]);
```

I would like to access the Expiration field in $hitInfo. It seems to require the use a special object accessor function.

```
       $hitInfo->get('Expiration');
```

...doesn't work.

What is the correct way to access the Expiration field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. :)

```
$HITdata = $hitInfo->get('HIT');
$newExpirationTime = $HITdata["Expiration"]->date;
```